# How can I get the Amazon Appstore to stop re-installing applications?

Tags: applications, amazon-appstore

Whenever I install an app through the Amazon store, I usually set my phone down while I wait for the download, and pick it up afterward to hit the "Install" button when the OS prompts me.  Sometimes I won't do this immediately.

It seems that the Appstore assumes the install failed if it wasn't completed within a certain length of time, and tries again.  This is fairly short (a minute or two) and sometimes it might be hours before I go back to my phone.  Until recently this wasn't a problem; I'd either just hit Install twice, or Install once and Cancel once, and move on.

Now, however, the Appstore seems to get stuck in a loop.  No matter how many times I hit Cancel or Install, it just repeatedly asks me to install the app.  I have to kill the Appstore and/or reboot my phone, ruining any other updates I have queued.  Then I have to wait for them again, and I'll probably forget about my phone for a few seconds too long and run into this issue again.

Is there any way to make the Appstore behave reasonably?

Comment: Does clearing data for the app store do anything?

Comment: @BryanDenny Like a reboot, it will fix the immediate issue (the one app constantly trying to install) but it will just happen again later.

Answer (score 1):

Try to clean out the `/sdcard/Android/data/com.amazon.venezia/cache` directory. This is where the apks are stored when initially downloaded, and they should be deleted when the application is installed. Seems for some reason, they are not always deleted, so it continued to ask to install it.

Comment: Wow, that folder had tons of stuff in it.  I got "There was an error parsing the package" when opening the Appstore the first time after clearing it, and got a notification saying the install was successful.  Thanks!  I wonder if there's anything I can do to help it keep the folder clear.  Obviously permissions aren't an issue with it being on the SD card...  **Edit:** After installing some new apps (without letting the install timeout, no issues) the .apks are left in the cache folder.  It seems it doesn't clean them out at all?  So perhaps the main issue is something else.

Comment: Mine had like 50+ files in it. Though I didn't get an error when I restarted the appstore after clearing it out.