# How can I purchase apps from the Amazon Appstore without downloading them?

Tags: applications, amazon-appstore

I've been procrastinating on swapping out my full 2 GB SD card for a 16 GB one I have, so I can't install many apps at the moment.  It's annoying to have to wait for a download and cancel the install that the Appstore attempts, and when updating other apps it only downloads one in the background (needlessly prolonging the experience, which leads to [other issues](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/18141/1465)).

Is there any way I can buy an app, or add the Free App of the Day to "My Apps", without downloading and installing it?  I can't just wait and do it another day, since the daily deal obviously won't apply then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can buy them from the website without downloading them. Any apps purchased through amazon.com simply get added to your account. I think that's the best you can really do.

Comment: Hmm, does work.  I tend to forget to check daily things like this on websites so I hope they add an in-app method.

Comment: @MatthewRead: I'd prefer an in-app way of doing it, too, but I still haven't found one :(