# Is it possible to buy the FAOTD (Free App Of The Day) from the Amazon App Store without downloading it?

Tags: applications, amazon-appstore

Sometimes the Amazon App Store has a FAOTD (Free App Of The Day) that I'm interested in getting, but I don't want to download it quite yet.  I just want it in my list of bought apps.

Is there a fast way to get the FAOTD without downloading it?  Priority given to answers that use the Amazon App Store, but will consider all options.

Comment: [How can I purchase apps from the Amazon Appstore without downloading them?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18143/how-can-i-purchase-apps-from-the-amazon-appstore-without-downloading-them)

Comment: Thank you very much!  What is the best way to proceed?  That question is nearly identical, but is almost 2 years old.  What is the appropriate way to get a current answer?  Also, the answer provided in that QA did not use the Amazon App Store.  Let me know how to proceed, and I'll do what's recommended.